# How to get SMS message code to be copy to input fields directly

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im building an login page in Angular7, the user need to insert username and password, and for Authorisation getting SMS code of 4 numbers to his mobile.
Then the sms pop ups from above(OUTSIDE of the app in his mobile phone), and "clicking" on it makes the sms code to copy automatically to the 4 inputs fields in the application.
its only works at IPhone, any idea how to achieve this on android ?

Comment: Can you please post some working  demo of what you are trying to achieve and where you are stuck ?

Comment: @dota2pro https://tidbits.com/2018/10/04/sms-text-message-login-codes-autofill-in-ios-12-and-mojave-but-remain-insecure/ this is what im tring to achive

Comment: iOS specifically provides for this feature. Android does not (yet)... android users will have to do it the old fashioned way

Comment: @bryan60 what is the old fashioned way?

Comment: going to there messages and looking at the code then going back and typing it in obviously...